# What do the vertical lines represent in Seaborn bar charts?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to use Seaborn factorplot from this [tutorial](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical_linear_models.html).

The following code creates a bar chart with vertical lines. What do those vertical lines represent?

```
sns.factorplot("kind", "pulse", "diet", exercise, kind="bar")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are errorbars.  According to the page you linked to:

> By default the height of the bars/points shows the mean and 95% confidence interval