# What are the small vertical lines in the line chart drawn from factorplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, data-analysis

The graph below is created with Seaborn's `factorplot()` and shows a line chart. I looked into the documentation of seaborn factorplot but found nothing related to the vertical lines mentioned in those documents.

[image: graph]

Comment: These lines represent a confidence interval. Default it would be the 95% interval. Seaborn draws these automatically when there are more y-values to a given x, and the dot represents the mean of these values. You seem to be running an old version of seaborn, as `factorplot()` doesn't form part of the current version.  There is `catplot()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the vertical lines represent in Seaborn bar charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771864/what-do-the-vertical-lines-represent-in-seaborn-bar-charts)